# Adaptive cards question on displaying data

Tags: templates, adaptive-cards

I am making an adaptive card for a work project and had a question on how to display the 4 types of label values(100G, Daily Values, Serving Size, Finished Piece Weight) under the appropriate toggle visibility section. I am able to display the product information but am having trouble with the label values. I have included the template and Data

Template

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.2",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Nutritional Approvals",
            "id": "Title Text",
            "size": "ExtraLarge",
            "weight": "Bolder",
            "horizontalAlignment": "Center"
        },
        {
            "type": "Container",
            "style": "emphasis",
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "ColumnSet",
                    "columns": [
                        {
                            "type": "Column",
                            "items": [
                                {
                                    "type": "TextBlock",
                                    "size": "Large",
                                    "weight": "Bolder",
                                    "text": "**APPROVAL**"
                                }
                            ],
                            "width": "stretch"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Column",
                            "items": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Image",
                                    "url": "https://adaptivecards.io/content/pending.png",
                                    "altText": "Pending",
                                    "height": "30px"
                                }
                            ],
                            "width": "auto"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "Container",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "ColumnSet",
                            "columns": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Column",
                                    "width": "stretch",
                                    "items": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "ActionSet",
                                            "actions": [
                                                {
                                                    "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
                                                    "title": "EXPORT AS PDF",
                                                    "url": "https://adaptivecards.io"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "bleed": true
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Product Information",
            "id": "Product Information",
            "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
            "size": "Large"
        },
        {
            "type": "Container",
            "id": "ProdInfoContainer",
            "items": [
                {
                    "$data": "{propertiesProductInformation}",
                    "type": "FactSet",
                    "facts": [
                        {
                            "title": "Item Number",
                            "value": "{ItemNumber}"
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Item Type",
                            "value": "{ItemType}"
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Branch Plant",
                            "value": "{BranchPlant}"
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Line ID",
                            "value": "{LineID}"
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Product Description",
                            "value": "{ProductDescription}"
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Stocking Type",
                            "value": "{StockingType}"
                        }
                    ],
                    "id": "ProdInfoFactSet"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Nutrition",
            "id": "Nutrition Text Block",
            "size": "Large",
            "horizontalAlignment": "Center"
        },
        {
            "type": "Container",
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "ActionSet",
                    "actions": [
                        {
                            "type": "Action.ToggleVisibility",
                            "title": "100G",
                            "targetElements": [
                                "factsethundred"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "ActionSet",
                    "actions": [
                        {
                            "type": "Action.ToggleVisibility",
                            "title": "Daily Values",
                            "targetElements": []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "ActionSet",
                    "actions": [
                        {
                            "type": "Action.ToggleVisibility",
                            "title": "Finished Piece Weight",
                            "targetElements": []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "ActionSet",
                    "actions": [
                        {
                            "type": "Action.ToggleVisibility",
                            "title": "Serving Size",
                            "targetElements": []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "ActionSet",
                    "actions": [
                        {
                            "type": "Action.ShowCard",
                            "title": "Reject",
                            "style": "destructive",
                            "card": {
                                "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                                "body": [
                                    {
                                        "type": "Input.Text",
                                        "id": "RejectCommentID",
                                        "placeholder": "Please specify an appropriate reason for rejection.",
                                        "isMultiline": true
                                    }
                                ],
                                "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json"
}
```

Data

```
{
  "propertiesProductInformation": [
    {
      "ItemNumber": "3022",
      "ItemType": "Finished Good",
      "BranchPlant": "10100 PLANT",
      "LineID": "PN1",
      "ProductDescription": "RETAIL",
      "StockingType": "S",
      "propertiesNutrition": [
        {
          "Label_Type": "100G",
          "propertiesNutrition_Label_Details": [
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Calories",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Calories",
              "Current_Value": 160.750,
              "New_Value": 160.750,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Calories from SatFat",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Calories",
              "Current_Value": 0.651,
              "New_Value": 0.651,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Protein",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Grams",
              "Current_Value": 4.411,
              "New_Value": 4.411,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Carbohydrates",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Grams",
              "Current_Value": 33.913,
              "New_Value": 33.913,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Dietary Fiber (2016)",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Grams",
              "Current_Value": 0.932,
              "New_Value": 0.932,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Soluble Fiber (2016)",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Grams",
              "Current_Value": 0.052,
              "New_Value": 0.052,
              "Flag": false
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Total Sugars",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Grams",
              "Current_Value": 0.772,
              "New_Value": 0.772,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Added Sugar",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Grams",
              "Current_Value": 0.352,
              "New_Value": 0.352,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Fat",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Grams",
             "Current_Value": 0.477,
              "New_Value": 0.477,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Saturated Fat",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Grams",
              "Current_Value": 0.072,
              "New_Value": 0.072,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Mono Fat",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Grams",
              "Current_Value": 0.043,
              "New_Value": 0.043,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Poly Fat",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Grams",
              "Current_Value": 0.236,
              "New_Value": 0.236,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Trans Fatty Acid",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Grams",
              "Current_Value": 0.000,
              "New_Value": 0.000,
              "Flag": false
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Cholesterol",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Milligrams",
              "Current_Value": 0.000,
              "New_Value": 0.000,
              "Flag": false
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Vitamin B1 - Thiamin",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Milligrams",
              "Current_Value": 0.346,
              "New_Value": 0.346,
              "Flag": false
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Vitamin B2 - Riboflavin",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Milligrams",
              "Current_Value": 0.180,
              "New_Value": 0.180,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Vitamin B3 - Niacin Equiv",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Milligrams",
              "Current_Value": 2.777,
              "New_Value": 2.777,
              "Flag": false
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Vitamin B3 - Niacin",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Milligrams",
              "Current_Value": 2.777,
              "New_Value": 2.777,
              "Flag": false
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Vitamin D - mcg",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Micrograms",
              "Current_Value": 0.221,
              "New_Value": 0.221,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Folate",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Micrograms",
              "Current_Value": 82.963,
              "New_Value": 82.963,
              "Flag": false
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Calcium",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Milligrams",
              "Current_Value": 7.426,
              "New_Value": 7.426,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Iron",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Milligrams",
              "Current_Value": 2.711,
              "New_Value": 2.711,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Magnesium",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Milligrams",
              "Current_Value": 5.428,
              "New_Value": 5.428,
              "Flag": false
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Phosphorus",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Milligrams",
              "Current_Value": 21.062,
              "New_Value": 21.062,
              "Flag": false
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Potassium",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Milligrams",
              "Current_Value": 49.537,
              "New_Value": 49.537,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Sodium",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Milligrams",
              "Current_Value": 1.188,
              "New_Value": 1.188,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Ash",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Grams",
              "Current_Value": 0.126,
              "New_Value": 0.126,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Calories from Fat",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Calories",
              "Current_Value": 4.291,
              "New_Value": 4.291,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Folate, DFE",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Micrograms",
              "Current_Value": 127.341,
              "New_Value": 127.341,
              "Flag": false
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Folate, food",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Micrograms",
              "Current_Value": 19.566,
              "New_Value": 19.566,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Folic Acid",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Micrograms",
              "Current_Value": 63.397,
              "New_Value": 63.397,
              "Flag": false
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Gram Weight",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Grams",
              "Current_Value": 64.500,
              "New_Value": 64.500,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Insoluble Fiber (2016)",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Grams",
              "Current_Value": 0.469,
              "New_Value": 0.469,
              "Flag": false
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Net Carbs",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Grams",
              "Current_Value": 33.913,
              "New_Value": 33.913,
              "Flag": true
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "Label_Type": "Daily Values",
          "propertiesNutrition_Label_Details": [
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Calories",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Calories",
              "Current_Value": 0.000,
              "New_Value": 0.000,
              "Flag": false
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Protein",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Grams",
              "Current_Value": 0.000,
              "New_Value": 0.000,
              "Flag": false
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Carbohydrates",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Grams",
              "Current_Value": 0.000,
              "New_Value": 0.000,
              "Flag": false
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Dietary Fiber (2016)",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Grams",
              "Current_Value": 0.000,
              "New_Value": 0.000,
              "Flag": false
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Total Sugars",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Grams",
              "Current_Value": 0.000,
              "New_Value": 0.000,
              "Flag": false
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Added Sugar",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Grams",
              "Current_Value": 0.000,
              "New_Value": 0.000,
              "Flag": false
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Fat",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Grams",
              "Current_Value": 0.000,
              "New_Value": 0.000,
              "Flag": false
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Saturated Fat",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Grams",
              "Current_Value": 0.000,
              "New_Value": 0.000,
              "Flag": false
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Trans Fatty Acid",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Grams",
              "Current_Value": 0.000,
              "New_Value": 0.000,
              "Flag": false
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Cholesterol",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Milligrams",
              "Current_Value": 0.000,
              "New_Value": 0.000,
              "Flag": false
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Vitamin D - mcg",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Micrograms",
              "Current_Value": 0.000,
              "New_Value": 0.000,
              "Flag": false
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Calcium",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Milligrams",
              "Current_Value": 0.000,
              "New_Value": 0.000,
              "Flag": false
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Iron",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Milligrams",
              "Current_Value": 0.000,
              "New_Value": 0.000,
              "Flag": false
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "Label_Type": "Finished Piece Weight",
          "propertiesNutrition_Label_Details": [
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Calories",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Calories",
              "Current_Value": 160.000,
              "New_Value": 160.000,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Protein",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Grams",
              "Current_Value": 4.000,
              "New_Value": 4.000,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Carbohydrates",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Grams",
              "Current_Value": 34.000,
              "New_Value": 34.000,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Dietary Fiber (2016)",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Grams",
              "Current_Value": 1.000,
              "New_Value": 1.000,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Total Sugars",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Grams",
              "Current_Value": 1.000,
              "New_Value": 1.000,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Added Sugar",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Grams",
              "Current_Value": 0.000,
              "New_Value": 0.000,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Fat",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Grams",
              "Current_Value": 0.000,
              "New_Value": 0.000,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Saturated Fat",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Grams",
              "Current_Value": 0.000,
              "New_Value": 0.000,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Trans Fatty Acid",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Grams",
              "Current_Value": 0.000,
              "New_Value": 0.000,
              "Flag": false
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Cholesterol",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Milligrams",
              "Current_Value": 0.000,
              "New_Value": 0.000,
              "Flag": false
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Vitamin D - mcg",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Micrograms",
              "Current_Value": 0.200,
              "New_Value": 0.200,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Calcium",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Milligrams",
              "Current_Value": 10.000,
              "New_Value": 10.000,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Iron",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Milligrams",
              "Current_Value": 2.700,
              "New_Value": 2.700,
              "Flag": true
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "Label_Type": "Serving Size",
          "propertiesNutrition_Label_Details": [
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Ash",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Grams",
              "Current_Value": 0.197,
              "New_Value": 0.197,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Calories from Fat",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Calories",
              "Current_Value": 5.000,
              "New_Value": 5.000,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Folate, DFE",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Micrograms",
              "Current_Value": 200.000,
              "New_Value": 200.000,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Folate, food",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Micrograms",
              "Current_Value": 30.785,
              "New_Value": 30.785,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Folic Acid",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Micrograms",
              "Current_Value": 99.748,
              "New_Value": 99.748,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Gram Weight",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Grams",
              "Current_Value": 100.000,
              "New_Value": 100.000,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Insoluble Fiber (2016)",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Grams",
              "Current_Value": 0.738,
              "New_Value": 0.738,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Net Carbs",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Grams",
              "Current_Value": 53.358,
              "New_Value": 53.358,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Water",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Grams",
              "Current_Value": 38.275,
              "New_Value": 38.275,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Calories",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Calories",
              "Current_Value": 250.000,
              "New_Value": 250.000,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Protein",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Grams",
              "Current_Value": 7.000,
              "New_Value": 7.000,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Carbohydrates",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Grams",
              "Current_Value": 53.000,
              "New_Value": 53.000,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Dietary Fiber (2016)",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Grams",
              "Current_Value": 1.000,
              "New_Value": 1.000,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Soluble Fiber (2016)",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Grams",
              "Current_Value": 0.082,
              "New_Value": 0.082,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Total Sugars",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Grams",
              "Current_Value": 1.000,
              "New_Value": 1.000,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Added Sugar",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Grams",
              "Current_Value": 1.000,
              "New_Value": 1.000,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Fat",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Grams",
              "Current_Value": 1.000,
              "New_Value": 1.000,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Saturated Fat",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Grams",
              "Current_Value": 0.000,
              "New_Value": 0.000,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Trans Fatty Acid",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Grams",
              "Current_Value": 0.000,
              "New_Value": 0.000,
              "Flag": false
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Cholesterol",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Milligrams",
              "Current_Value": 0.000,
              "New_Value": 0.000,
              "Flag": false
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Vitamin B1 - Thiamin",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Milligrams",
              "Current_Value": 0.500,
              "New_Value": 0.500,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Vitamin B2 - Riboflavin",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Milligrams",
              "Current_Value": 0.300,
              "New_Value": 0.300,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Vitamin B3 - Niacin Equiv",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Milligrams",
              "Current_Value": 4.400,
              "New_Value": 4.400,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Vitamin B3 - Niacin",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Milligrams",
              "Current_Value": 4.400,
              "New_Value": 4.400,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Vitamin D - mcg",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Micrograms",
              "Current_Value": 0.300,
              "New_Value": 0.300,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Folate",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Micrograms",
              "Current_Value": 130.000,
              "New_Value": 130.000,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Calcium",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Milligrams",
              "Current_Value": 10.000,
              "New_Value": 10.000,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Iron",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Milligrams",
              "Current_Value": 4.300,
              "New_Value": 4.300,
              "Flag": true
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Magnesium",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Milligrams",
              "Current_Value": 10.000,
              "New_Value": 10.000,
              "Flag": false
            },
            {
              "Nutritional_Desc": "Phosphorus",
              "JDE_UOM_Description": "Milligrams",
              "Current_Value": 30.000,
              "New_Value": 30.000,
              "Flag": false
            }        
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

had a look at your Data its a bit tricky indeed.

Id recommend changing the naming of your props to use camelcase without hyphens...lot easier.

You have to do a few  things:

- Add a container below the toggle button for each category
- Add a factset to that container, set id and add id as target for your toggle button
- Add a where condition to the container "where type = 100G"

Try this template:

```
{
"type": "AdaptiveCard",
"version": "1.2",
"body": [
    {
        "type": "TextBlock",
        "text": "Nutritional Approvals",
        "id": "Title Text",
        "size": "ExtraLarge",
        "weight": "Bolder",
        "horizontalAlignment": "Center"
    },
    {
        "type": "Container",
        "style": "emphasis",
        "items": [
            {
                "type": "ColumnSet",
                "columns": [
                    {
                        "type": "Column",
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "type": "TextBlock",
                                "size": "Large",
                                "weight": "Bolder",
                                "text": "**APPROVAL**"
                            }
                        ],
                        "width": "stretch"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "Column",
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "type": "Image",
                                "url": "https://adaptivecards.io/content/pending.png",
                                "altText": "Pending",
                                "height": "30px"
                            }
                        ],
                        "width": "auto"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "type": "Container",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "ColumnSet",
                        "columns": [
                            {
                                "type": "Column",
                                "width": "stretch",
                                "items": [
                                    {
                                        "type": "ActionSet",
                                        "actions": [
                                            {
                                                "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
                                                "title": "EXPORT AS PDF",
                                                "url": "https://adaptivecards.io"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "bleed": true
    },
    {
        "type": "TextBlock",
        "text": "Product Information",
        "id": "Product Information",
        "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
        "size": "Large"
    },
    {
        "type": "Container",
        "id": "ProdInfoContainer",
        "items": [
            {
                "$data": "{propertiesProductInformation}",
                "type": "FactSet",
                "facts": [
                    {
                        "title": "Item Number",
                        "value": "{ItemNumber}"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Item Type",
                        "value": "{ItemType}"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Branch Plant",
                        "value": "{BranchPlant}"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Line ID",
                        "value": "{LineID}"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Product Description",
                        "value": "{ProductDescription}"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Stocking Type",
                        "value": "{StockingType}"
                    }
                ],
                "id": "ProdInfoFactSet"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "type": "TextBlock",
        "text": "Nutrition",
        "id": "Nutrition Text Block",
        "size": "Large",
        "horizontalAlignment": "Center"
    },
    {
        "type": "Container",
        "items": [
            {
                "type": "ActionSet",
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "type": "Action.ToggleVisibility",
                        "title": "100G",
                        "targetElements": [
                            "factsethundred"
                        ],
                        "id": ""
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "type": "Container",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "FactSet",
                        "$data": "{propertiesProductInformation[0].propertiesNutrition[0].propertiesNutritionLabelDetails}",
                        "$when": "{LabelType ='100G'}",
                        "facts": [
                            {
                                "title": "{NutritionalDesc}",
                                "value": "{NewValue}"
                            }
                        ],
                        "id": "factsethundred"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "type": "ActionSet",
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "type": "Action.ShowCard",
                        "title": "Reject",
                        "style": "destructive",
                        "card": {
                            "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                            "body": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Input.Text",
                                    "id": "RejectCommentID",
                                    "placeholder": "Please specify an appropriate reason for rejection.",
                                    "isMultiline": true
                                }
                            ],
                            "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
],
"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json"
```

}

See if that helps you in any way but it should.

Comment: That helped a lot, Thank you! One issue I was still having was that only the first "propertiesNutritionLabelDetails" nutrition fact was appearing and disappearing when I click on the toggle visibility for some reason. Everything beyond the first fact(Calories) is always visible. It seems like the "100G" Label only applies to the Calories fact right under it  in the data

Comment: hmm might need to try a few things myself, never actually had a nested array structure like you have there before. I expected the where to work as you expected yourself but not sure if it actually works that way.

Comment: I was able to figure it out. I had the toggle visibility targeting the factset Id when it should have been targeting the container id. Thanks again!